# Migrating stored procedures from Teradata BTEQ to Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to migrate stored procedures and related queries from Teradata BTEQ to Snowflake schema. But as snowflake doesn't support stored procedure, is there any way to get this done ?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript Stored Procedures are supported as of May 2019.

Other resources for migration:

- [Teradata to Snowflake Migration Guide](https://copycoding.com/d/teradata-to-snowflake-migration-guide)
- Roboquery
- https://www.mobilize.net/snowflake (unfortunately converts to Python instead of JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

The Stored Procedures logic might be implemented through a combination of Python scripts (running from a client computer) and UDFs written in JavaScript or SQL within Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures are now supported in Snowflake (in Javascript) as below

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures.html